# Shared state with aiohttp web server

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My `aiohttp` webserver uses a global variable that changes over time:

```
from aiohttp import web    

shared_item = 'bla'

async def handle(request):
    if items['test'] == 'val':
        shared_item = 'doeda'
    print(shared_item)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
web.run_app(app, host='somewhere.com', port=8181)
```

Results in:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shared_item' referenced before assignment

How would I properly use a shared variable `shared_item`?

Comment: You can instance classes to act as namespaces for your app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Push your shared variable into application's context:

```
async def handle(request):
    if items['test'] == 'val':
        request.app['shared_item'] = 'doeda'
    print(request.app['shared_item'])

app = web.Application()
app['shared_item'] = 'bla'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time finding an answer to this.

Comment: As of version 3.5.4 this is deprecated (`DeprecationWarning: Changing state of started or joined application is deprecated`). What's the recommended way of doing this now?

Comment: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/discussions/6804#discussioncomment-3066116