# Store future state on application object

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Is it ok to store the state of future directly on application object? Example below

```
import asyncio

async def background():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Doing something useful in the background')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


@aiohttp_jinja2.template('loading.html')
async def loading(request):
    app = request.app
    task = getattr(app, 'task_obj', None)
    if task is None:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(background())
        callback = partial(done_refresh, app)
        task.add_done_callback(callback)
        app.task_obj = task


def done_refresh(app, future):
    if hasattr(app, 'task_obj'):
        # Nice! Task is done
        del app.refreshing

    exc = future.exception()
    if exc is not None:
        # Task has some exception
        print('Failed to update: %s', exc)
```

Usually, I store some marker like `in_progress` in Redis and then check for that value from whatever function I want, but that way I lose `Task` object itself and will not be able to access useful data like exception info.
What is the common approach to handle such cases?

Comment: This question shows that it's ok to store variables in application context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616145/shared-state-with-aiohttp-web-server, but is there any caveats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach makes perfect sense, except that the task should be stored in the aiohttp app context, instead of being set as an attribute (`app['task_obj'] = ...` instead of `app.task_obj = ...`)

see also https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please

Comment: Thanks, that's it. As usually everything was in docs. But is there really any difference between setting an attribute vs. setitem approach?

Comment: Setting attribute will be forbidden in aiohttp 4.0.
Now it raises a warning in debug mode.